# value at risk calculation

Tags: probability

I am to count VaR for a portfolio consisting of $100$ diversified bonds. One bond which is worth $100$ can either give $105$ with $p=0,98$ or $0$ with $p=0,02$. 
This probability can be expressed as $105Y-5$ if I assume $Y$ to be a binary variable ($1$ with $p=0,02$ and $0$ with $p=0,98$).

How should I proceed to calculate VaR ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given confidence level $\alpha$, the value-at-risk (VaR) is the smallest value $x$ such that the loss $L$ would be exceeded with probability at most $1-\alpha$.

$$VaR_{\alpha} = \inf \{x:P(L>x)\leq(1-\alpha)\} $$

Initially there are $100$ bonds each worth $100$ for a total portfolio value of $V_0=10000.$ If there are $Y$ defaults in one period, the final portfolio value is $105(100-Y).$

Assuming that the bonds are uncorrelated (a strong interpretation of diversified), the number of defaults has a binomial distribution:

$$P(Y=k) = \binom{100}{k}(0.02)^k(0.98)^{100-k}.$$

To find VaR, we solve for the smallest integer $j^*$ such that

$$\sum_{k=j^*}^{100}\binom{100}{k}(0.02)^k(0.98)^{100-k} \leq 1-\alpha $$

Also it may be easier to approximate the binomial distribution as a normal distribution with mean $\mu = 100p= 2$ and variance $\sigma^2 = 100p(1-p)= 1.96.$

Then we would use the normal distribution function $N(x;\mu,\sigma)$ to find $j^*$ by solving

$$1-N(j^*;\mu,\sigma) = 1-\alpha.$$

At the $95$% confidence level, $1-\alpha = 0.05$ and we find $j^* \approx 5.$  With $5$ defaults, the final portfolio value is $105(100-5)=9975$ and $VaR_{0.95} = 25.$

Comment: Thanks RRL, that's exactly what I meant. How would you find the smallest j∗ if we assumed α = 0,95 ?

Comment: Trial and error with the binomial formula -- or better use the normal approximation I added to post.

Comment: The answer to this question is 25. The formula looks as follows:
VaR(L) = Var(∑(105Yi-5)) = 105Var(∑Yi) - 500 = 525 - 500 = 25 
I don't know how come ∑Yi=5 ... Could you come up with any explanation?
As you said Yi ~ Bin(100,0.02)

Comment: $Y_i = 5$ because that is the smallest number for which no more bonds default 95% of the time. In other words, $VaR_{95\%}$ means what is the value for which you expect to remain below 95% of the time. As the assumptions (default rate, independence) indicate that no more than 5 bonds are expected to default 95% of the time, and when 5 bonds default, the portfolio ends at a net position of a $25 loss, the VaR_95 is 25.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something fundamentally flawed with this @Pasato @RRL

$\sum_{k=j^*}^{100}\binom{100}{k}(0.02)^k(0.98)^{100-k} \leq 1-\alpha $

If $\alpha$ is .05 or .95

The minimal integer value of $j*$ for which that sum is valid under the constraints given that $\alpha= .95$ is 6.

The minimal integer value of $j*$ for which that sum is valid under the constraints given that $\alpha= .05$ is 1.

So, either you have not stated the solution clearly enough or there is something buggy happening here.

Comment: "Fundamentally flawed" is a bit strong.  At the 95% level we have $1 - \alpha = $ 0.05.   Directly from the binomial distribution, the probability of 4 or fewer defaults is 94.92% and 5 or fewer defaults is 98.45%.  I would argue that VaR is fixed by at least 5 defaults where the final portfolio value is 9975.  You can either subtract this from the initial portfolio value of 10000 or from the expected value of 0.98 x 105 x 100 = 10290 to determine VaR.  I've seen both conventions.  I'll check the calculations again but the threshold is going to be 4, 5 or 6. At this point I think 5.

Comment: @RRL well, this is a far cry from 25 as proposed above. Thank you for checking in though and outlining things. I think that I have used my pocket calculator to do this ... so, for $1 - \alpha=.05$ it should be 6 --not 25. P.S. u are correct. 5 is within $<$ ,6 is above.

Comment: The number 25 is simply the amount lost = 10000 - 9975 if there are 5 defaults.  I never said that VaR is set by 25 defaults.  VaR is a dollar amount lost.  As I said you could compute this as 10290 - 9975 if you accept 5 defaults as the threshold.  In practice there is no absolute answer -- one would look at all aspects of the distribution.  Perhaps it is 6 -- I'll check again.